# Angular-Chart property to labels and value to data

Tags: angular-chart

I am trying to map a result to an angular-chart but am confused on how to map my labels and map my data. My service returns an object that looks like this:

```
Object {0: 5, 4: 1, 9: 1, 14: 2}
```

**Question
How do I map my labels to the 0, 4, 9, 14  so that I can use it to put into a bar graph and data like below:**

```
angular.module("app", ["chart.js"]).controller("BarCtrl", function ($scope)     {
$scope.labels = ['0', '4', '9', '14'];
$scope.data = [
[5, 1, 1, 2]    
];
});
```

**Question 2 -- instead of using the numbers can I type in names for the labels?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by mapping the value to an array.

```
var array = $.map($scope.count, function (value, index) {
                return [value];
            });
            console.log(array);
```

Then using array on my chart.